# How to combine two strings in R to open a vector?

Tags: r

I need to use a vector called Solution3. How do I combine "Solution" with a "3" in order to open/use my existing vector already called Solution3. Tried using paste  and as.vector with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data by means of `dput(head(data))` and also your desired output. It would be much easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe this could be what you are looking for:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ solution3,
  1,
  2,
  3,
)

with(df, get(paste("solution", 3, sep = ""))

[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, consider

```
Solution <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Solution3 <- c(Solution, 3)
```